Ambiguous variable reference in C++
I have this piece of code
#include <iostream>

namespace ns{
    int a = 10;
}

using namespace ns;
int a = 20;

int main(){
    std::cout << a;
}

As per my understanding, when std::cout << a is evaluated, a is searched for in main's local scope. If not found, the lookup is performed in the global scope, where a is found. So, I was simply expecting it to print 20, but the code doesn't compile, claiming that
error: reference to 'a' is ambiguous

However, this code works :
#include <iostream>

namespace ns{
    int a = 10;
}

using namespace ns;
int a = 20;

int main(){
    std::cout << ::a;
}

It prints 20. Why does this difference arise? Shouldn't the two codes be equivalent, considering that a is not defined in main's scope, and the lookup is performed in the global scope in both the cases?
This is related to a similar question, but I want to specifically understand the difference caused by replacing a with ::a and how the two are not equivalent, rather than just ambiguous variable references.

Consider the first code. And consider what happens if programmers just think to use ns::a. So it is a nice feature to make explicit programmer errors, which would be difficult to find. We are not (modern) computers/compilers, so you should think computer languages also to address human factors (not just plain semantic).

both as can be found in the global namespace

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Which is also the case in the second piece of code, isn't it?

@RajdeepSindhu yes, but as the answer explains, only in the first case you ask the compiler to look for any a it can find. In the second you specifically ask for the one declared in the global scope

Take a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace, particularly the

Using-directive does not add any names to the declarative region in which it appears (unlike the using-declaration), and thus does not prevent identical names from being declared.

Since you're "only" doing a using ns instead of a using ns::a, you're not introducing the a into the global namespace. You are just telling the compiler to search the ns namespace in addition to the global one.
Thus, when you declare the a variables, there is no problem because one is in ns and one is in the global namespace. However, when you lookup an unqualified a, then all the ns members are considered to be part of the global namespace as well (because of the using), so now there are two a in the same namespace.
In your second example, the ::a explicitly tells to use the global namespace; it's not an unqualified lookup anymore. For this, the https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/qualified_lookup has this to say:

Qualified lookup within the scope of a namespace N first considers all declarations that are located in N ... If there are no declarations in that set then it considers declarations in all namespaces named by using-directives found in N ...

In other words, the "using" namespaces are considered AFTER the actual namespace, so there's no ambiguity anymore.

Thanks for the answer. Might be a little unrelated but would using using namespace ns inside main also tell the compiler to search ns in addition to the global namespace, or would it tell the compiler to search ns in addition to main's local namespace?

Within the scope of main(), using using namespace ns the way in the question has exactly the same effect as using using namespace ns in main().

using namespace affects only unqualified name lookup. In your second example, you refer explicitly to ::a, the symbol in the global scope. The compiler knows what you mean, all is well.
But in your first case, you refer only to a without any scope qualifier, so the compiler performs a lookup to figure out which a you mean, and that's where it runs into trouble because both ::a and the imported ns::a are visible.

If using namespace affects only unqualified name lookups, then why does the second piece of code work, if we remove the global int a = 20;? A qualified lookup of a is being affected by a using-directive, isn't it?
